# Error when updating retrofit2 to the version 2.9.0 from 2.6.0 seems to confilct with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am currently using Retrofit 2 and Firebase services in one project. The project is working fine but when I update Retrofit 2 Library to the new version (2.9.0), gradle synced perfectly but when running the app I get this error and the app fails. Error message: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

My dependencies in Gradle-app looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1' //for crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
```

Full error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.fm.csfm, PID: 8717
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fm.csfm-WHtOa5E0nJ2xAlJon-1HGQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.fm.csfm-WHtOa5E0nJ2xAlJon-1HGQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5851)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5772)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fm.csfm-WHtOa5E0nJ2xAlJon-1HGQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.fm.csfm-WHtOa5E0nJ2xAlJon-1HGQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6273)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5851) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5772) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.fm.csfm-WHtOa5E0nJ2xAlJon-1HGQ==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.fm.csfm-WHtOa5E0nJ2xAlJon-1HGQ==/base.apk': Bad method handle type 7
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:676)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:709)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:936)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2242)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5672)
            ... 8 more
```

Comment: This might help out https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372464/8649647

Comment: Sorry, but I need more info, show me the complete error log output.

Comment: I have edited the main thread and added the full error message

Comment: @princessdharmy I tried the suggested solution but did not work

Answer (score 1):

Got it through!

I found that the problem was not a conflict with Firebase as I have noticed that when I update Retrofit in other projects also gives other errors. The solution was to add JAVA 8 support as follow:

In Gradle-app:

```
android{
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```